# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' (only in vscode with venv)

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, modulenotfounderror

When I try to install **opencv-python** I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

I tried to install cv2 via these commands:

`pip install opencv-python`

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

`pip install opencv-python opencv-python-headless`

`python3 -m pip install opencv-python`

`pip3 install opencv-python --upgrade`

However, the problem remains.

I have noticed that **this problem occurs only in the virtual environment** (venv) of VScode.

In fact, **if I launch this code from the terminal it does not give me any error** and it returns me the version of `cv2`

```py
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)
```

Reply -> `4.6.0`

I use `Python 3.9`

**EDIT:**

This is a screenshot of the problem

The problem do not appear if I create a new venv

[image]

Comment: I have not issue problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette search and select **Python:Select Interpreter**, then select the correct interpreter, this will solve your problem.

[image]

***Tip***: Every time you choose a new interpreter, please create a **new terminal** to activate the environment.

[image]

**As far as your question is concerned, you can follow these steps:**

1. Select the interpreter in the virtual environment according to the above method
2. Create a new terminal
3. Use `pip install opencv-python` to install the package

Also you can use `pip show opencv-python` to see where the package is installed.

[image]

Comment: Hi @JialeDu Unfortunately the problem remains. I had already tried but nothing changes. And yes if I use `pip show opencv-python` from the venv terminal it replies with the package information as if it were correctly installed... but VSC keeps reporting the opposite.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to help you out. Can you provide more screenshots of the project structure and error messages and opencv package information?

Comment: Hi @JialeDu. I added a screenshot of the problem

Comment: Obviously, the `opencv` package shown in your picture is not in your virtual environment. this is my [machine](https://imgur.com/a/y7gj31m).

Comment: You're right @JialeDu. But if I install it from the venv why does it install outside of it?

Comment: As said in my answer, after changing the interpreter you need to activate the new environment. If you just select the interpreter in the virtual environment without activating the virtual environment, the package will still be installed in the previous environment. After the virtual environment is activated it should look like the picture in my answer: the virtual environment name is displayed at the top of the command line.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was adding the following to the `.vscode/settings.json` config file

```json
    // Add venv to python path
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages"
    ]
```

change `venv` to the name of your virtual env folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got probably the same problem. Although I was inside the virtual environment, pip did not installed OpenCV into the particular sub-folder:

```
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
```

but always to the global /python/site-packages:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages
```

So I forced the usage of the "virtual env" pip by calling it directly:

```
.venv/bin/python3.11 -m pip install opencv-python
```

(Assuming your virtual environment is in .venv, you may change that ;))

Now the library was place into:

```
.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/
```

And I could import cv2.